# Chain of ideals in nilpotent algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, algebras

Let $R$ be a nilpotent algebra ($R^n = \{0\}$ for some $n \ge 1$) and $A$ be a subalgebra of $R$.
I want to show that exist a finite chain of subalgebras {$R_i$  | $i = 0, 1, ..., m $}, $m \ge 1$, such that $$R_0 = \{0\} \lhd R_1 = A \lhd R_2 \lhd \ldots \lhd R_m = R$$
($\lhd$ - Two-Sided ideal)

**Update:**
As a finite chain we can take: $R \rhd R^{2} \rhd \ldots \rhd R^n =\{0\}$. Then just add A to this chain. So we get: $\{0\} \subseteq R^{n}+A=A \subseteq R^{n-1}+A \subseteq \ldots \subseteq R + A = R$. So the question is how to show that it is still a chain of ideals? Math induction?

Comment: You can always take the idealization of a subset of $R$ to go one step up, but it's not clear to me why the steps would necessarily be strictly increasing, or why they would terminate in finitely many steps, so I'm not sure if it's helpful.

Comment: @rschwieb, you can take as an ideal chain $R^1, R^{2}, \dots, R^{n}$

Comment: Sure, of course that builds a chain from $R$ down to $\{0\}$, but I'm saying the procedure I described for building a chain with each link a $\lhd$ starting at $A$ may not be useful.

Comment: Update in the top